# Autostart does not work after user reboot

Tags: linux, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, autostart

I want to autostart a sh script after reboot.

I add below line to  `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`.

`@/home/pi/mog/run.sh`

Everything works fine if i plug the raspberrypi-2 to power line or switch on it after halt. However when i run shell command 
`sudo shutdown -r now` the autostart method does not work after reboot?

I want to run a C++ application after reboot and my run.sh script is below.

`#!/bin/bash
 sleep 5
 /home/pi/mog/mog -platform xcb`

Comment: I have solved my problem by using    `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` instead of  `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` .Now everything works fine. I can not understand how this solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends on what type of shell script you are trying to run.

Looks like there are several ways to do it:

**1. Start with Console**

Create a file for your startup script and write your script in the file:

```
 $ sudo nano /etc/init.d/superscript
 Save and exit: Ctrl+X, Y, Enter
```

Make the script executable:

```
 $ sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/superscript
```

Register script to be run at startup:

```
 $ sudo update-rc.d superscript defaults
```

**2. Start At Login**

Make sure you are in the pi folder:

```
 $ cd ~
```

Create a file and write a script to run in the file:

```
 $ sudo nano superscript
```

Paste contents of sh script here

```
 Save and exit: Ctrl+X, Y, Enter
```

Open up .bashrc for configuration:

```
 $ sudo nano .bashrc
```

Scroll down to the bottom and add the line: ./superscript

```
 Save and exit: Ctrl+X, Y, Enter
```

**3. Start with Desktop Environment**

(Your method which sounds like its not working for your needs)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to edit your crontab.

```
$crontab -e
```

or

```
$sudo crontab -e
```

The last line should be

```
@reboot /home/pi/mog/run.sh
```

If it doesn't work you can try creating an autostart folder

```
mkdir ~/.config/autostart
cd ~/.config/autostart
```

create a .desktop file like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=yourscript.sh
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=Startup Script
```

Move your yourscript.sh in /usr/local/bin folder and it should run after reboot