# Rapberry pi rc.local,crontab @restart not running on boot

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I'm running Raspian on a Raspberry Pi. I want to run a script on startup, but nothing seems to be working. To test it, I'm currently just putting solely

```
echo "Helloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo"
```

into /etc/rc.local after the default lines of # (directly after, before 'return 0')

However, it does not run at boot.

I tried putting the command into the crontab, with

```
@restart echo "Helloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo"
```

but that also fails to work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: In the case of cron the output is captured. You may want to try instead of "echo" doing something like "touch /tmp/hello" or "date > /tmp/hello" to confirm if things are working.

Comment: Also, confirm that the cron daemon runs on startup if @restart is not working.

Comment: @sam Alright, the date > /tmp/hello works! Thank you! I'm still confused as to why rc.local isn't working, but this is certainly good enough for now. You've really saved me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@restart echo "Helloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo" > /dev/tty
```

See, if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put your echo command in a bash script and read my response here:  [Autostart does not work after user reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35481305/autostart-does-not-work-after-user-reboot/35613735#35613735)